# php get image size from a string of image content

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

I have a function that would fetch a remote image via CURL, returning a string variable of the contents of the remote image.

I do not wish to write the content into the file, but wish to get the size of the image.

since getimagesize() only supports a file, is there a function similar to getimagesize() but can support strings of image content?

to clarify:

```
$image_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/example.jpg');
```

how to get the image size of `$image_content` instead of running `getimagesize('http://www.example.com/example.jpg');`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: image dimensions or file size?

Comment: @Dagon image dimensions. i would suspect filesize can be achieved through `strlen()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP functions [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php), [imagesx](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php), and [imagesy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php).

Something like this;

```
$image_content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/example.jpg');
$image = imagecreatefromstring($image_content);
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
```

Answer (score 7):

FYI, for those coming late to the game, PHP >= 5.4 now includes `getimagesizefromstring()` which is identical to `getimagesize()` but accepts a string for the first param instead of a location.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found answer for PHP 5.3 and less

```
if (!function_exists('getimagesizefromstring')) {
    function getimagesizefromstring($data)
    {
        $uri = 'data://application/octet-stream;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        return getimagesize($uri);
    }
}
```